# read div and check for a click condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, constructor, callback, intervals

```js
let timer    = document.querySelector("#timer");
var counter = 3;

function myFn() {
  counter--
  if (counter === -1) {
    counter = 3
  }
  timer.innerText = counter
}

btn.onclick = function() {
  text.innerHTML += 'clicked' + '<br>'
}

var myTimer = setInterval(myFn, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
<button id="btn">Button</button>
<div id="text"></div>
```

I'm trying with this small code to read the `div#timer` every second and check for a click condition in console.log() F12. It gives me different error in every way I try to do it.

```
let timer = document.querySelector("#timer");
let btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(timer.textContent)
  if (timer.textContent === '0') {
    btn.click()
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Your question, nor the goal, make any sense. If you want to detect a click, use a click event handler. What does the timer have to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following jQuery example.

```js
$(function() {
  var timer = 0;
  var counter = 3;
  var timeObj = $("#timer");
  var btnObj = $("#btn");
  var txtObj = $("#text");
  var interval;

  function myFn() {
    if (--counter >= 0) {
      txtObj.append("Clicked<br />");
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }

  interval = setInterval(function() {
    timeObj.html(++timer);
  }, 1000);

  btnObj.click(myFn);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer">0</div>
<button id="btn">Button</button>
<div id="text"></div>
```

You will want to use `setInterval()` and not `setTimeout()`.

> The `setInterval()` method, offered on the Window and Worker interfaces, repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call.

> This method returns an interval ID which uniquely identifies the interval, so you can remove it later by calling `clearInterval()`.

See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Using the `--` and `++` before the variable will also apply the change before it is used.

> The decrement operator (`--`) decrements (subtracts one from) its operand and returns the value before or after the decrement, depending on where the operator is placed.

Adjusting the logic here can also ensure that the button click does allow the user to keep performing actions.